# Is this answer right?

Tags: geometry

There is a pentagon inscribed in a circle with a diameter of 10. What is the area and perimeter? Is the answer 20 and 25? I tried using examples and applying them to the problem.

Comment: A skinny pentagon would have smaller perimeter and area. What kind of pentagon do you have?

Comment: A regular pentagon. @user21820

Comment: The area of the regular pentagon is made up of 5 congruent triangles. The area of one is given by 0.5 ab sin C; where a = b = 5 and C = 2(pi)/5

Answer (score 1):

The regular pentagon can be partitioned into $5$ identical triangles sharing a vertex at the centre, so its area is $5$ times the area of each triangle, which is $\frac{1}{2} r^2 \sin(\frac{360^\circ}{5}) = \frac{r^2}{2} \frac{\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}}{1+\sqrt{5}}$, where $r$ is the radius of the circumscribing circle. So the total area is $\frac{5r^2}{2} \frac{\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{5}}}{1+\sqrt{5}}$. The perimeter is just $5$ times the edge length, which is $2 r \cos(\frac{360^\circ}{10}) = 2 r \frac{\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}}{2\sqrt{2}} = r \frac{\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}}{\sqrt{2}}$. So the total perimeter is $5 r \frac{\sqrt{5-\sqrt{5}}}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming regular pentagon and usage of Trigonometry is accepted,

If one side is  $a$ unit

using Cosine Law of Triangle on the triangle formed by two radii and one of the sides of the pentagon ,  $$\cos\frac{2\pi}5=\frac{5^2+5^2-a^2}{2\cdot5\cdot5}$$

Now the area of $n$ sided regular Polygon is $$na^2\cot\frac\pi n$$

What about the perimeter?

Comment: @downvoter, What is wrong here?

Comment: At first you only had the first part, which is actually a detour when the area can be directly obtained without finding the side length, and even then the cosine law is unnecessary because the triangles are isosceles.